# .NET | EF Core: What is the best practice for implementing a "staging/pending changes" data layer between SQL Server and API?

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, blazor, publish

I'm looking for a simple pattern that will "stage" incoming data changes from requests to my API before adding to/updating the "published" production data.

**Intended Workflow**

1. User edits form in the UI & presses "save"
2. Model is sent to the API
3. API stages that data
4. API exposes that data to GETs when specifically prompted (i.e. Get /person?includeDrafts=true, etc.)
5. User decides it is time to publish those changes
6. Publish request is sent to API
7. Staging data is merged to production data

**Stack**

- SQL Server
- .NET Core Web API
- Blazor WebAssembly

I've spent the last few days sourcing various methods of accomplishing this and have struggled to find many resources - maybe I'm just missing the vernacular to google it properly?

I'm thinking I just need a push in the right direction.

Comment: The simplest starting approach would be to just save the data into another table with same/similar structure.